# Can be rewritten the custom attribute parameter defined in controller (ASP.NET MVC3)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have some actions defined in controller which modify file content (of course, I don't modify directly from controller but this controller calls the methods from model). Over that function, I put a custom attribute which mention that must have admin rights.

The action looks like:

```
[CustomAttribute(MustBeAdmin = true)]
public ActionResult ModifyFile(){
  ...
}
```

and `CustomAttribute` looks like:

```
public class CustomAuttribute: AuthorizeAttribute 
{
   public bool MustBeAdmin {get;set;}

   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest( AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
       if ( filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["user"] == null ) { ... }
       else { ... // check if is need admin rights and current has this right then continue else go to default route }
   }
}
```

I want to ask you, for security purpose, if someone can set `MustBeAdmin` parameter to  false value from outside of code ?

If yes, how to prevent this ?

Thanks